# Copy paste values within cell range

Tags: vba, excel, range, copy-paste

Following on from my previous question, I would now like to copy paste values within a cell range.

The code used in my previous query was;

```
Sub CopyYesInW()
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
'determine last row in column W
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastRow
    'if Yes in W then copy from P to W in current row
    If Cells(i, "W").Value = "Yes" Then
        Cells(i, "P").Value = Cells(i, "P").Value
    End If
    If Cells(i, "W").Value = "Yes" Then
        Cells(i, "U").Value = Cells(i, "U").Value
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

I have amended the code in the script below to check the the cell range `C6:N6` for values = `Yes` then copy paste values over the cells in `C9:N9`.  However I am not sure what I am doing wrong. There is a runtime error '5' invalid procedure call or argument

```
Sub CopyYesInForecast()
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
'determine last row in column W
lastRow = Cells("C6")
For i = 1 To lastRow
'if Yes in W then copy from P to W in current row
    If Cells(i, "C6:N6").Value = "Yes" Then
        Cells(i, "C9:N9").Value = Cells(i, "C9:N9").Value
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You can get the code for copy/pasting your range by recording the action with a macro and then editing to view the generated code. (See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/recording-a-macro-to-generate-code) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/revising-recorded-visual-basic-macros).) After that, it sounds like you'll only need a simple `IF` statement.

Comment: what was wrong in the first code? Why not make the question clear and only show the second code example and state clearly what the error is?

Comment: @pnuts There is a runtime error '5' invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: I suggest you google or look up the Cells and Range syntax in VBA help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your narrative is thin, perhaps this is close to what you are attempting.

```
Sub CopyYesInForecast()
    Dim c As Long

    For c = range("C:C").column to range("N:N").column
        If Cells(6, c).Value = "Yes" Then
            Cells(9, c) = Cells(6, c).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This looks through row 6, column C to N and if it finds *Yes* then it transfers the value to the same column in row 9.

Comment: Thanks, apologies for the poor description of the problem